# ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'pc.project_id' in 'on clause' even when column project_id exists

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to get a sum from my DB with a query written in hibernate

```
@Query(value = "SELECT COALESCE(sum(charge),0) FROM initial_charge I INNER JOIN task T ON T.id = I.task_id "
+" INNER JOIN project_collab PC ON PC.collab_id=T.collaborator_id "
        + " INNER JOIN project P ON P.id = pc.project_id "
+ "where P.id = :idProject AND T.collaborator_id = :idCollab ", nativeQuery = true)
double sumInitialChargeByCollab(@Param("idProject") int idProject , @Param("idCollab") int idCollab);
```

The problem is, I get nothing in return.
When I tried it directly in mysql I got this error :

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'pc.project_id' in 'on clause'
```

even though the column exists in the table

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query text cleared from external code dirt is:

```
SELECT COALESCE(sum(charge),0) 
FROM initial_charge I 
INNER JOIN task T ON T.id = I.task_id 
INNER JOIN project_collab PC ON PC.collab_id=T.collaborator_id 
INNER JOIN project P ON P.id = pc.project_id 
where P.id = :idProject 
  AND T.collaborator_id = :idCollab
```

If case-dependence is enabled then `PC` and `pc` are two different names.

Convert ALL table/column/alias names to the same case (lower preferred).

PS. If `charge` (by the way, what table does this field come from?) is not nullable then COALESCE is excess.